# Javascript Shadowing - Effect if you try to change an already existing global variable w/o using the VAR keyword

Tags: javascript, global-variables, var, local-variables, shadowing

So, I understand that declaring a variable without the **var** keyword means it's declared in the global scope.

So in the 1st example below, Line 4 of the code changes the global variable **person** (which does not have the **var** keyword preceding it) from "Jim" to "Andrew."

```
var person = "Jim";

function whosGotTheFunc() {
   person = "Andrew";
}

person = "Nick";
whosGotTheFunc();
console.log(person);
```

And in the 2nd example, Line 4 of the code creates a separate local variable, also entitled **person**.

```
var person = "Jim";

function whosGotTheFunc() {
   var person = "Andrew";
}

person = "Nick";
whosGotTheFunc();
console.log(person);
```

*However, what does Line 7 of both examples do?* The line that says:
    **person = "Nick";**

The Treehouse quiz asks what is logged to the console. In example #1, Line 4 changes the global variable **person** to "Andrew" but then Line 7 does NOT affect that global variable (so the console logs "Andrew")... However, in example #2, after Line 4 creates a local variable, Line 7 does, in fact, change the value of the global variable from "Jim" to "Nick" (the console logs "Nick").

What I want to know is in the 2 examples, ***why the difference in behavior of Line 7: person = "Nick"???***

Comment: !!!! Never mind, it took me 45 minutes of writing this question out to figure out the answer to my own question !!!

Comment: Hahaha. It's cuz the whosGotTheFunc() is run afterwards, which in example #1, changes the global to "Andrew," whereas in example #2, the same execution of that function does not change the value of the global variable cuz, by using the var keyword, it's creating a local variable (so global person is still equal to "Nick")...

Comment: PS: this was definitely worth the 45 minutes I just spent on it!!!

Answer (score 0):

The variable is modified in both examples. However, the call to `whosGotTheFunc()` is *after* the global modification, so in the first example, it overwrites the value of "Nick", leaving it at "Andrew".

Comment: Thank you Jake King! Haha, before reloading the page and seeing your answer, I was able to figure it out but your help is def appreciated!!!

Comment: @user2649656 No problem, happens to the best of us. If you think my answer helped you, would you kindly accept it? Thanks!